# How to migrate passwords from Kwallet to the GNOME keyring?

Tags: google-chrome, migration, gnome-keyring, kwallet

I migrated from KDE to Unity desktop. So all my passwords I used with Chromium and Iron-browsers are stucked in Kwallet.

How to access passwords from Kwallet inside Unity? Maybe there is way that browsers could use still Kwallet? Or some way for migration?

I use now Ubuntu 12.04, Kwallet was in Kubuntu 11.10.

Edit. Results so far:

I tried to use Kwallet under Unity2d, but if Chrome/Iron does not ask directly from Kwallet (and it does not, it uses Seahorse under Unity2d), the data saved to Kwallet from Chrome/Iron is useless.

I exported from Kwallet as XML and tried to load it to KeyPassX, but result is same, because Chrome/Iron data is unreachable. When i look data through the Kwallet, there is said: "This is binary entry. It cannot be edited as its format is unknown and application specific".

Only way i see, is to install KDE somewhere and try export data from Chrome/Iron directly, but i still hope to have better solution.

Comment: @desgua: Tried now, it does not work. It looks for "a file containing at least one ASCII armored public key" (as manual says). .kwl file does not suit here.

Comment: @desgua: You pointed to Kleopatra docs, in Kwallet docs is nothing about present export funtionality. If Kleopatra is capable handling of Kwallet, i had to like know about it.

Comment: I had problem with Kwallet too, because it did not start. As it sorted out, it started, but did not had windows. So from here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeutils/+bug/576284 i got hint to use '--show' key. Appears, Kwallet can export to file, but only as XML. So we got some steps forward, but stuck in the middle... Copying/dragging to file manager directs to .kwl files.

Comment: @wk - please re-edit your question with what you have tried from the above comments.  When done, these comments can then be deleted.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way i see, is to install KDE, login to KDE-session and try export data from Chrome/Iron directly.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.keepassx.org/faq

> What password database formats are compatible with KeePassX?
>
> KeePassX currently uses the KeePass 1.x (Classic) password database format as the native format.
> It can also import KeePassX 1.x XML exports, PwManager databases and KWallet XML databases.
> KeePass 2.x database format is not supported.

Shouldn't the import option work seamlessly ?
(as i cannot replicate on my side,this is all the help i can give.)

Maybe try with a "Classic" version of the database to see if this one imports better than the newer one.

you could also look at the xml structure of the file  you want imported and make a shell script to extract the data from it or to process it into another format which can more easily imported (in a case where the import direct from the KWallet file isn't working..)

the source file of the import function (Import_KWalletXml.cpp) might give some clues of the steps to accomplish for a successful import..
http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid79C723FF3B0D62F83C9CD5F65CB87DE2D8F3D713.aspx

Comment: What you mean with "Classic version"? Yes, import works seamlessy with some data, but does not help with data i am looking for (Chrome/Iron forms data), which is saved in Kwallet in application specific format and so not imported to the KeePassx.

Comment: if you look in my response  the "Classic" version refers to the KeePass 1.x database format..

Comment: So which exact steps are you suggesting? Sorry, i still don't get it...

Comment: export from kwallet to keepassx 1.x format
then import in keepassx from that one..

Comment: Kwallet knows only one Import/Export format: XML